# Sample to have an equal number of each sex within groups in R

Tags: r, statistics

First things, first. Here are my data:

```
lat <- c(12, 12, 58, 58, 58, 58, 58, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 45, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64, 64)
long <- c(-14, -14, 139, 139, 139, 139, 139, -68, -68, -68, -68, -68, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1)
sex <- c("M", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "F", "M", "M", "M", "F", "M", "F", "M", "F", "F", "F", "F", "M")
score <- c(2, 6, 3, 6, 5, 4, 3, 2, 3, 9, 9, 8, 6, 5, 6, 7, 5, 7, 5, 1)

data <- data.frame(lat, long, sex, score)
```

The data should look like this:

```
   lat long sex score
1   12  -14   M     2
2   12  -14   M     6
3   58  139   M     3
4   58  139   M     6
5   58  139   F     5
6   58  139   M     4
7   58  139   M     3
8   45  -68   F     2
9   45  -68   M     3
10  45  -68   M     9
11  45  -68   M     9
12  45  -68   F     8
13  45    1   M     6
14  64    1   F     5
15  64    1   M     6
16  64    1   F     7
17  64    1   F     5
18  64    1   F     7
19  64    1   F     5
20  64    1   M     1
```

I am at my wits end trying to figure this one out. The variables are latitude, longitude, sex and score. I would like to have an equal number of males and females within each location (i.e. with the same longitude and latitude). For instance, the second location (rows 3 to 7) has only one female. This female should be retained and one male from the remaining individuals should also be retained (by random sampling, perhaps). Some locations have only information about one sex, e.g. the first location (rows 1 and 2) has only data on males. The rows from this location should be dropped (since there are no females). All going according to plan the final dataset should look something like this:

```
   lat2 long2 sex2 score2
1    58   139    F      5
2    58   139    M      4
3    45   -68    F      2
4    45   -68    M      3
5    45   -68    M      9
6    45   -68    F      8
7    64     1    M      6
8    64     1    F      5
9    64     1    F      7
10   64     1    M      1
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: @Mnel will be along shortly and explain how to do this with `data.table`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Below is a quick way to go about it, which involves creating a temporary column of the lat-long combination. We split the DF according to this column, count the M/F in each split, sample appropriately, then re-combine.

```
# First, We call the dataframe something other than "data" ;) 
mydf <- data.frame(lat, long, sex, score)

# create a new data frame with a temporary column, which concatenates the lat & long. 
mydf.new <- data.frame(mydf, latlong=paste(mydf$lat, mydf$long, sep=","))

# Split the data frame according to the lat-long location
mydf.splat <- split(mydf.new, mydf.new$latlong)

# eg, taking a look at one of our tables:
mydf.splat[[4]]

sampled <- 
  lapply(mydf.splat, function(tabl) {
    Ms <- sum(tabl$sex=="M")
    Fs <- sum(tabl$sex=="F")

    if(Fs == 0 || Ms ==0)    # If either is zero, we drop that location
      return(NULL)

    if(Fs == Ms)   # If they are both equal, no need to sample. 
      return(tabl)

    # If number of Females less than Males, return all Females 
    #    and sample from males in ammount equal to Females
    if (Fs < Ms)   
      return(tabl[c(which(tabl$sex=="F"), sample(which(tabl$sex=="M"), Fs)),   ])

    if (Ms < Fs)  # same as previous, but for Males < Femals
      return(tabl[c(which(tabl$sex=="M"), sample(which(tabl$sex=="F"), Ms)),   ])

    stop("hmmm... something went wrong.")  ## We should never hit this line, but just in case. 
  })

# Flatten into a single table
mydf.new <- do.call(rbind, sampled)

# Clean up
row.names(mydf.new) <- NULL  # remove the row names that were added
mydf.new$latlong <- NULL     # remove the temporary column that we added
```

#### RESULTS

```
mydf.new

#    lat long sex score
# 1   45  -68   F     2
# 2   45  -68   F     8
# 3   45  -68   M     9
# 4   45  -68   M     3
# 5   58  139   F     5
# 6   58  139   M     3
# 7   64    1   M     6
# 8   64    1   M     1
# 9   64    1   F     7
# 10  64    1   F     5
```

Comment: Your first steps could more economically accomplished using split( ..., drop=TRUE), and returning a dataframe with no rows will "disappear" during the rbind step.

Comment: Thanks a million for this Ricardo! While it was not the most economical of solutions provided, it was definitely the most helpful for me. I am still getting a handle on R and the comments are very useful in understanding what the code is actually doing.

Comment: @DWin, not sure if I followed..? The split list used to create `sampled` does not contain any empty rows.  The result `sampled` _does_, and they do disappear in the `do.call` step.  Can you clarify what I am overlooking? Thanks

Comment: @Ciaran, glad it was helpful.  I cleaned up some of the comments in the recent edit.

Comment: @RicardoSaporta: I just thought creating the `latlong` character vector was not needed. You can just do `split(df, fac1, fac2, drop=TRUE)` and the names are created automagically.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a solution with `lapply`:

```
data[unlist(lapply(with(data, split(seq.int(nrow(data)), paste(lat, long))),
        # 'split' splits the sequence of row numbers (indices) along the unique
        # combinations of 'lat' and 'long'
        # 'lapply' applies the following function to all sub-sequences
        function(x) {
          # which of the indices are for males:
          male <- which(data[x, "sex"] == "M")
          # which of the indices are for females:
          female <- which(data[x, "sex"] == "F")
          # sample from the indices of males:
          s_male <- sample(male, min(length(male), length(female)))
          # sample from the indices of females:
          s_female <- sample(female, min(length(male), length(female)))
          # combine both sampled indices:
          x[c(s_male, s_female)]                
        })), ]
# The function 'lappy' returns a list of indices which is transformed to a vector
# using 'unlist'. These indices are used to subset the original data frame.
```

The result:

```
   lat long sex score
9   45  -68   M     3
11  45  -68   M     9
12  45  -68   F     8
8   45  -68   F     2
7   58  139   M     3
5   58  139   F     5
20  64    1   M     1
15  64    1   M     6
19  64    1   F     5
16  64    1   F     7
```

Comment: 1+ Nice. At first it looked to me that you were building a large collection of dataframe components, but then I realized you were doing it with indices.

Comment: Sven, thanks for your solution. It would be really helpful for me if you included some information as to what the code is doing.

Comment: much more elegant than the long if-chains i put together.

Answer (score 2):

This returns the values as list elements:

```
spl <- split(data, interaction(data$lat, data$long) ,drop=TRUE)
           # interaction creates all the two way pairs from those two vectors
           # drop is needed to eliminate the dataframes with no representation
res <- lapply(spl, function(x) { #First find the nuber of each gender to select
                        N=min(table(x$sex))  # then sample each sex separately
   rbind( x[ x$sex=="M" & row.names(x) %in% sample(row.names(x[x$sex=="M",] ), N) , ],
                 # One (or both) of these will be "sampling" all of that sex.
          x[ x$sex=="F" & row.names(x) %in% sample(row.names(x[x$sex=="F", ]), N) , ] )
                                } )
res
#------------
$`45.-68`  
   lat long sex score
9   45  -68   M     3
11  45  -68   M     9
8   45  -68   F     2
12  45  -68   F     8

$`12.-14` # So there were no women in this group and zero could be matched
[1] lat   long  sex   score
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

$`45.1`
[1] lat   long  sex   score
<0 rows> (or 0-length row.names)

$`64.1`
   lat long sex score
15  64    1   M     6
20  64    1   M     1
16  64    1   F     7
17  64    1   F     5

$`58.139`
  lat long sex score
7  58  139   M     3
5  58  139   F     5
```

,,,, but if you wanted it as a dataframe you can just use `do.call(rbind, res)`:

```
> do.call(rbind, res)
          lat long sex score
45.-68.10  45  -68   M     9
45.-68.11  45  -68   M     9
45.-68.8   45  -68   F     2
45.-68.12  45  -68   F     8
64.1.15    64    1   M     6
64.1.20    64    1   M     1
64.1.17    64    1   F     5
64.1.18    64    1   F     7
58.139.6   58  139   M     4
58.139.5   58  139   F     5
```

Comment: Thanks for this DWin. As I also mentioned in regards to Sven's solution above, it would also be helpful for me if you could explain what the code is doing. I've only been using R for a few months and I am still getting to grips with it. Cheers!

Comment: I did not know about `interaction`!  Very useful.  I see what you were saying now about using `drop`.  In stead of interaction, I created a dummy column